# ArgumentError in CertificatesController#import wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Extracted source (around line #7):
5
6
7
8
9
10

return redirect_to request.referer, notice: 'Only CSV files allowed' unless params[:file].content_type == 'text/csv'

CsvImportService.new(file: params[:file]).call

redirect_to request.referer, notice: 'Import started ...'

Rails.root: /home/ricardo/CSV

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/certificates_controller.rb:7:in `initialize' app/controllers/certificates_controller.rb:7:in` new'
app/controllers/certificates_controller.rb:7:in `import'

i have a CsvImportService file with code below:

```
class CsvImportService
  require 'csv'

  attr_reader :file

  def initilize(file:)
    @file = file
  end

  def call(file)
    debugger
    opened_file = File.open(file)
    options = { headers: true, col_sep: ';' }
    CSV.foreach(opened_file, **options) do |row|

      # map the CSV columns to your database columns
      certificate_hash = {}
      certificate_hash[:name] = row['name']
      certificate_hash[:email] = row['email']
      modifications = {}
      modifications[:name] = row['modifications.name']
      modifications[:description] = row['modifications.description']
      modifications[:issued_on] = row['modifications.issued_on']
      modifications[:issued_by] = row['modifications.issued_by']

      certificate_hash[:modifications] = modifications

      certificate_hash.find_or_create_by!(certificate_hash)

      # for performance, you could create a separate job to import each user
      # CsvImportJob.perform_later(user_hash)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This part og the code in the controller seems to be the problem: CsvImportService.new(file: params[:file]).call please tell me what i am doing wrong

Comment: You spelled initialize wrong.

Comment: Change `def initilize(file:)` to `def initialize(file:)`.

Comment: Thank you so much.. I feel so stupid.. I really appreciate it..